# How to remove the first weather in weather forecast using weather api

Tags: javascript, typescript, weather-api

here's the code.

```
setWeatherForecast(unit: any, scaleTemp: any) {
    this.forecast.splice(0, this.forecast.length);
    this.weatherService.getLocation().subscribe(data => {
      this.lat = JSON.parse(data['_body']).latitude;
      this.lon = JSON.parse(data['_body']).longitude;

      this.weatherService
        .fiveDayForecast(this.lat, this.lon, unit)
        .subscribe(forecastData => {
          for (let i = 0; i < forecastData.list.length; i = i + 8) {
            console.log(forecastData.list[i]);
            const forecastWeather = new Forecast(
              forecastData.city.name,
              forecastData.list[i].weather[0].description,
              forecastData.list[i].main.temp.toFixed(0) + scaleTemp,
              forecastData.list[i].dt_txt.replace(/\s/, 'T'),
              forecastData.list[i].weather[0].icon
            );
            this.forecast.push(forecastWeather);
          }
          return this.forecast;
        });
    });
  }
```

what I want is to remove the first weather in weather forecast.
for example.

friday, saturday, sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday

it will remove the saturday. it only display the sunday to tuesday.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.forecast.splice(0,1);
```

or

```
this.forecast.shift()
```

for more clarification see this [link](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/javascript-remove-element-array/)

Now first index removed from your forecast array.

Comment: it replace the sunday to tuesday

Comment: {...friday},{...saturday}, {...sunday}, {...monday}, {...tuesday} output. but it remove the saturday to tuesday instead it will remove the friday

Answer (score 1):

You should use splice

```
this.forecast.splice(0, 1)
```

where 0 is the index position and 1 the number of element to remove

example

```
list=["bar", "baz", "foo", "qux"]
list.splice(2, 1)
// Starting at index position 2, remove one element
["bar", "baz", "qux"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`return this.forecast.shift();`

to remove the first weather in forecast.

you can use the `shift()` - method removes the first element from an array and returns that removed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift